# Google Distance Matrix Api

Tags: google-distancematrix-api

anyone know, how to use google distance matrix Api but destination from webserver?
for example, i want to use google distance matrix api and latitude longitude destination from this url sempatbimbel.esy.es/actions/jsontbimbel.php

Answer (score 0):

I know it is late. First, you need to get the IP address of this website (like ping in the ASP,PHP,....), then convert the IP to lat/long, something like this http://geoipinfo.org/  . Now, you have two sets of coordinates: Geo coordinates of the website and your destination. 
then pass these geolocations to Google AP like this

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=40.6655101,-73.89188969999998&destinations=40.6905615%2C-73.9976592%7C40.6905615%2C-73.9976592%7C40.6905615%2C-73.9976592%7C40.6905615%2C-73.9976592%7C40.6905615%2C-73.9976592%7C40.6905615%2C-73.9976592%7C40.659569%2C-73.933783%7C40.729029%2C-73.851524%7C40.6860072%2C-73.6334271%7C40.598566%2C-73.7527626%7C40.659569%2C-73.933783%7C40.729029%2C-73.851524%7C40.6860072%2C-73.6334271%7C40.598566%2C-73.7527626&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro